# How to get GPS coordinates with leaflet.extras addControlGPS

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm using the **leaftlet.extras** R package to add Gps control inside a map.
I'm using the extension **addControlGPS** inside my code :

```
...   %>% 
addControlGPS(options = gpsOptions(position = "topleft", activate = TRUE, 
                                             autoCenter = TRUE, maxZoom = 60, 
                                             setView = TRUE))  %>%
...
```

The controller works ok.

I need to extract the Gps coordinates to re-use in my code as arguments for other functions. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time the gps location updates, the coordinates are written to `map.id+'_gps_located'`. You can find all `leaflet.extras` bindings in the  [htmlwidgets/bindings](https://github.com/bhaskarvk/leaflet.extras/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/bindings/lfx-gps-bindings.js) folder in their git.

**Working example**

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput('map')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({ leaflet()%>%addTiles() %>% 
      addControlGPS(options = gpsOptions(position = "topleft", activate = TRUE, 
                                         autoCenter = TRUE, maxZoom = 60, 
                                         setView = TRUE))})
  observe(
    print(input$map_gps_located)
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had a similar problem with an app I was working on.

You can extract the gps coordinates from a leaflet map by using the _marker_click feature, where  is the map label you specify as an output for the leaflet rendering statement.

In my case here's the chunk of code I used to retrieve the coords. In my case the output name of the map object was `parksMap` therefore the full input to consider in the event observation was `parksMap_marker_click`. This statement can be saved in a variable (in my case `pin`), that stores the coordinates data. Finally you need to wrap it all in a reactive expression to be able to save every coordinate when clicking on a point in the leaflet map.

```
# code to load the park card once the click event on a marker is intercepted 
 observeEvent(input$parksMap_marker_click, { 
   pin <- input$parksMap_marker_click
   #print(Sys.time()) #uncomment to log coords
   #print(pin) #uncomment to log coords
   selectedPoint <- reactive(parks[parks$Latitude == pin$lat & parks$Longitude == pin$lng,])
   leafletProxy("parksMap", data = selectedPoint()) %>% clearPopups() %>% 
   addPopups(~Longitude,
             ~Latitude,
             popup = ~park_card(selectedPoint()$ParkName, selectedPoint()$ParkCode, selectedPoint()$State, selectedPoint()$Acres, selectedPoint()$Latitude, selectedPoint()$Longitude)
   )
 })
```

The full github repo of the app is available [here](https://github.com/abenedetti/bioNPS).